# Generating several similar SSIS packages (file data source to DB)

Tags: sql-server, csv, file-io, ssis

Is there a way to automatically generate SSIS packages? I need to create a lot of SSIS packages that just erase data from one table and import data from a text file. The file name matches table name and the column headers are in the first line of the file.

For more detailed information:

- I am working on a project in which I have to separate two systems that are currently coupled (one system has direct access to the other's database). After the modifications, one system will provide data through txt files to be loaded in the other database.
- We have to use SSIS to load data into the database from the text files.
- The text files will be provided in CSV format with column headers in the first line.
- The tables from both databases have matching column names, and all we need to do is clear the table and load data from the files.

I have more than one hundred tables with different number of columns. Do I need to create each package manually?

Comment: if all 100 packages will always run at the same time (overnight, for example,) you could have one package with 100 steps and one sp clearing all 100 tables.

Answer (score 2):

I'm familiar with 2 free options.

- [EzAPI](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/21238) might be a good place if you're a .NET heavy shop or just really want to geek out with the API. This approach allows you to control the pretty much the entire package generation but at the cost of coding time. I find EzAPI generally easier than working with the base COM/.NET libraries for SSIS.
- [Biml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biml) is an interesting beast. Varigence will be happy to sell you a license to Mist but it's not needed. All you would need is [BIDSHelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) and then browse through [BimlScript](http://www.bimlscript.com/) and look for a recipe that approximates your needs. Once you have that, click the context sensitive menu button in BIDSHelper and whoosh, it generates packages.

Answer (score 0):

I did this just using vb, I passed in the table names as a command parameter and used vb to generate the insert and clear, worked a charm... I can try and dig it out tomorrow when I'm back in the office but it was pretty simple. There didn't seem to be any other way to say "just get x and export it", "just take y and import it into z" so vb it had to be. In fact come to think of it I think I actually used a small xml file to pass the table info for export and then determined the table name for import from the csv file name. To be clear, this was only one package but it could dynamically choose the number of imports/exports it did. Further clarification this was vb within ssis as a processing step